# Cross Thread Error Trying To Open New Form Instance Inside Timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I am trying to create little notification popups for my application and have created a new form that fades in and out and sits on top of my main form (seems to work okay).

My problem is that I have some code that sits inside a timer event that does some data checking every minute or so.  Depending on the data results, I sometimes need to show a notification.  However, it is causing me Cross-Thread errors (which is understandable), but I'm not sure how to get around it.

Example (in a nutshell) of what I am trying to do is:

```
Private Sub RefreshData(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    Try
        MainRefreshTimer.Interval = GetInterval()
        MainRefreshTimer.Start()

        'Do some data checking here...
        If data returns true then
            Dim notify as New frmNewNotification("Some Text", 10) '<== Show some text for 10 seconds then close the form automatically
            notify.Show() '<== Cross Thread Error occurs from this
        End If
    ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Do **not** use a System.Timers.Timer, many things wrong with it.  You don't need anything more than the Timer you find back in the toolbox.

Comment: @HansPassant I suppose you're my downvoter. I use that 'answer' on my Threads. What the main reason for -1? Not to advise of using system.windows.forms.timer? Really want to know. No hard feelings :)

Comment: It was not me.  But surely *somebody* was horrified at you giving this user a gun to shoot his leg off.  Setting Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to *false* is a horrible workaround, the programmer loses all hope of diagnosing the occasional deadlock he'll get.  It is completely undebuggable.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you see anything wrong with the `InvokeRequired` method, as that's what I implemented and it seems to be working fine.  I did steer clear of the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` as I already knew that was a 'loaded gun' so to speak.  :)

Comment: There just completely isn't any point in writing that code.  It is not better than using a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.  It is in fact worse, much worse.  The threading race you get when the user closes the window but the timer keeps on ticking, or has scheduled a tick, will crash your program randomly.  Not often enough to find out that the code is broken.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans for the reply.  Would it be possible to post a different solution then?  Or is that becoming off-topic?  I am just eager to get a solution to this issue. Thanks

Comment: I don't really understand why somebody has to post to inspire you to use the correct Timer class.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, I'm confused!  You said I shouldn't use the System.Timers.Timer in one post, then another saying it's not better than using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer. I was only asking you to post an example if you felt that I shouldn't use a timer at all and there was a better method.  I will change my code to a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.  Thanks

Comment: @Riples This is that he is talking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer

Comment: @HansPassant I only answered the question 'as is'. But Riples. really he's right about System.Timers.Timer. 
My anwer it's ok for something like a controlled Threading.Thread. But *System.Timers.Timer*, has issues discussede here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416803/system-timers-timer-vs-system-threading-timer.
Maybe you can simply paste a Forms.Timer, and play with Tick Event. I'll mantain my answer for future readers. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I would try one of this ideas:

***Shorcut***: Put this in your Form_Load

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

Or, **better**, something like:

```
Private Sub delRefreshData(data as Object)
  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    ' Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf delRefreshData)) ' no params
    Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() delRefreshData(data)))
  Else
    'Do some data checking here...
      If data returns true then
       Dim notify as New frmNewNotification("Some Text", 10) 
       notify.Show() '
      End If
  End if
```

[Using InvokeRequired vs control.InvokeRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527947/invoke-required)

**Edited:**
To avoid in future be blamed for that Shorcut, I have to say that 
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls isn't a good advice/solution, as is discussed here:

[Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353857/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: I couldn't use the `MethodInvoker` because it wouldn't accept any values and the RefreshData routine has `sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs`.

Comment: Changing your example to `Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() RefreshData(Me, Nothing)))` seems to be working for me.  I will keep testing...

Comment: oh! sure, it's wrong, because it's "Private SUB" :) I was wrong. Edited.